# How can we access rels file of a slide thorugh code?

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to access  `rels` file for slide   for example `"\ppt\slides\_rels\slide1.xml.rels"`
through open xml   `C#`, how can i do this ?, or is there any property or method that returns these relationships.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you open your ppt document in C# code you can use the following way to access the `_rels`

```
using(PresentationDocument myDoc = PresentationDocument.Open("yourfilepath",true))
{
    var reqPart = myDoc.Package.GetPart(new Uri("/ppt/slides/_rels/slide1.xml.rels", UriKind.Relative));

}
```